# LIMIT in SQL query with left join

Tags: mysql, sql, pagination, left-join, limit

I mam SQL Query to me reads categories and we want to do paged category also have used the SQL query to me their statements:

```
public function fetchChildrenNodess($start,$end){
        $q_offset = (int)$start;
        $q_limit = (int)($end - $start);

$query= "select k1.id as id from ".Config::tableKategorie." k1 left join ".Config::tableKategorie."  k2 on k2.nlft<k1.nlft and k2.nrgt>k1.nrgt and k2.nlft>".$this->L." and k2.nrgt<".$this->R." where k1.nlft>".$this->L." and k1.nrgt<".$this->R." and k2.id is null  order by k1.nlft ";

         $i=0; $ret=array();
        // $hash=$this->hash().'_part_'.$start.'_'.$end;


             $Q=mysql_query($query."LIMIT 0, 8 ",CommerceDB::$DB);
             while($R=mysql_fetch_assoc($Q)){
                 $ret[]=new Kategoria($R['id']);

         };

         return $ret;





    }
```

If we use limit here

```
$Q=mysql_query($query."LIMIT 0, 8 ",CommerceDB::$DB);
```

so I listed only 9 subsubcategory and go to the next subcategory. Subcategory also writes and 9 categories too. I need to get my listing only include a maximum 8 results. Well thank you

Answer (score 0):

In this solution, your function should just have 1 parameter, which you can increment (next) or decrement (prev). I assume that your query and other codes work fine.

Page parameter is in sequence of 1-N. And do not let user specify the **end value** if the goal is to limit the recordset up to 8 rows.

```
public function fetchChildrenNodess($page){

   $range_const = 8; // # of rows to show; constant value

   if( $page > 0 ) // what if page is 0 or less ???
       $start = ($range_const * ($page-1)); // start limit
   else
       $start = 0;

   $end = $range_const - $start; // end limit

   $query= "select k1.id as id from ".Config::tableKategorie." k1 left join ".Config::tableKategorie."  k2 on k2.nlft<k1.nlft and k2.nrgt>k1.nrgt and k2.nlft>".$this->L." and k2.nrgt<".$this->R." where k1.nlft>".$this->L." and k1.nrgt<".$this->R." and k2.id is null  order by k1.nlft ";
   $query = $query . ' LIMIT ' . $start . ',' . $end . ';'

   $i=0; $ret=array();

   $Q = mysql_query($query,CommerceDB::$DB);
   while($R=mysql_fetch_assoc($Q)){
       $ret[]=new Kategoria($R['id']);
   }
}
```

**Test Case**

```
+----------+--------+------+
| Page Num | $start | $end |
+----------+---------------+
|    1     |   0    |   8  |
|    2     |   8    |   8  |
|    3     |  16    |   8  |
|    4     |  24    |   8  |
|          |        |      |
|    0     |   0    |   8  |
|   -1     |   0    |   8  |
+----------+--------+------+
```